# Uimask changes min max lentgh of ng-minlength

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

```
<div layout="column">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <label translate>Company Phone</label>
        <input name="companyPhoneNumber"
               ui-mask="0(999)-9999999"
               ng-model="vm.model.companyPhoneNumber"
               ng-required="true"
               ng-minlength="11"
               maxlength="11"
               md-maxlength="11" />

        <div ng-messages="form.companyPhoneNumber.$error" ng-if="form.companyPhoneNumber.$dirty"
             role="alert" ng-messages-multiple>
            <div ng-message="md-maxlength">
                <span translate translate-values="{length:11}">global.messages.error.max</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-message="minlength">
                <span translate translate-values="{length:11}">global.messages.error.min</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'pattern']">
                <span translate>global.messages.error.phoneNumber</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

[image: it shows this]

it shows 14 chars but i did not fill anything.

[image: they are overlaping]

I want to show only string. But when user clicks, it should write 54343 into that field.

And it should only put 11 chars. Not 14.

So using text input 2 times is better idea?

my mask normally has

(999)-9999999

11 char but it also counts

(
) and - so it becomes 14. but they are not char

small part of controller

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('signup')
        .controller('SignUpController', SignUpController);

    SignUpController.$inject = [
        '$state',
        '$timeout',
    ];
    /* @ngInject */
    function SignUpController($state, $timeout, Account, AuthServer, Alert, Principal, StringUtil ) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.model = {};

        vm.companyMask = "0(999)-999-999";




    function signUp() {



        Account.register(vm.model).success(
            function (emptyData, status, headers) {

                AuthServer.checkAuthenticationToken(headers, true);
                Principal.identity(true).then(
                    function (account) {
                        var companyShortInfo = {

                            companyPhoneNumber: vm.model.companyPhoneNumber,
                            }
                        };


                    }
                );

            }
        )
    }
```

ui-mask added to the module in a module such as

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular
    .module(
  'app.tracking',  
        'angular-google-analytics',
        'ui.mask'
```

Comment: Is _ui-mask_ compatible with Material Design _md-input-container_?

Comment: I think no. it shows 14 chars even i did not fill. what can  use as alternatie?

Comment: can you please include your ui-mask config and a small portion of you controller

Comment: @alphapilgrim i added some snippets. is it enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you accept one suggestion, from the UX perspective, the counter is useless in this case. Simply remove it. The mask states that you need to fulfill the entire field to correct inform the value.

But, if you did REALLY need this, you can define a controller method to calculate the amount of digits that were already informed:

```
function Controller() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.inputValue = null;

    vm.calculateDigits = function _calculateDigits(value) {
        return (value + '').match(/([0-9]{1})/g).length;
    };
}
```

Remember that ui-mask only add the value to $modelValue or $viewValue of the ngModel after it's valid, returning undefined before (unless you already typed something valid before).

### Edit 1:

To work with this function on the view you need to place an Angular Expression like this:

```
<p class="help-block">{{ vm.calculateDigits(vm.model.companyPhoneNumber) }}</p>
```

Comment: where to put calculateDigits in div layout,, i couldnot figure it out?

Comment: Edited the answer with an use example.

Comment: It gave null error so i put if not equal null to start of it, else return 0. This time only shows 0. WHen i enter phone, 0 doesnot change and it is not red in the picture like 17/11 .i  want to change md-max mdmin part.

Comment: That's what I said on the answer: the value of ngModel ($modelValue or $viewValue, doesn't matter in this case) will be `undefined` until the user enter a valid value that fit into the defined mask. There's A LOT of modifications to be made, maybe a directive to access the ui-mask scope, for example, to retrieve this info on the go. Again: it's better remove this, it doesn't worth the effort. I bet that you didn't saw any forms on the wild that use this mask and a counter together.